# Calculator program returns tkinter error in python

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I am trying to write a program with a very simple interface for a calculator. I still have to add some functions to it, however, i tested my code so far and i get a very weird tkinter error. Could you please explain to me what is the problem ?
This is the error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/application /App1.py", line 8, in process
    number1 = Entry.get(E1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2682, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

And this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

def process():
    try :
        number1 = Entry.get(E1)
        number2 = Entry.get(E2)
        operator = Entry.get(E3)
        number1 = int (number1)
        number2 = int ( number2)
        if operator == "+" :
            answer = number1 + number2
        Entry.insert(E4,0,answer)
        print(answer)
    except ValueError:
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning", "Please enter the value in integer")

top = tkinter.Tk()


L1  = Label(top, text ='My calculator',).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)
L2 = Label (top, text = "Number 1",).grid(row = 1 , column = 0)
L3 = Label (top, text = 'Number 2',).grid (row = 2, column = 0)
L4 = Label (top, text = 'Operator',) . grid (row=3, column = 0)
L5 = Label (top, text = 'Answer:',) . grid ( row = 4, column = 0)
E1 = Entry (top, bd = 5,).grid( row = 1 , column = 1)
# OR : E1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
E2 = Entry ( top , bd = 5,).grid( row = 2, column = 1)
E3 = Entry ( top, bd = 5,).grid(row = 3, column = 1)
E4 = Entry ( top, bd = 5,).grid(row=4, column= 1 )
B = Button(top, text = "Submit here: ", command = process).grid (row = 5 , column = 1,)


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```.grid()``` method returns ```None```. What you should be doing is ```E1= Entry(top, bd=5)``` and then ```E1.grid(row=1,column=1)``` Let me know if this helps

Comment: @LazyCoder yes, thank you so much. The explanation would be that the Entry.grid is only building the interface while Entry is also returning something? When sould i use entry.grid then, do you have any idea?

Comment: @LazyCoder All right, thank you lots. Have a good day!

Comment: Entry creates an object. While grid calls a method that returns None. You need object reference with E1. So that's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.grid()` method returns `None`. What you should be doing is `E1= Entry(top, bd=5)` and then `E1.grid(row=1,column=1)` The error will resolve itself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `Entry.get(...)` is correct, i.e. that `get` is a static/class method,  or should you be creating an instance of `Entry` and calling `get` on that?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues

1. The `.grid()` method returns `None`, hence you are assigning `None` to your variables. You should break them into two lines, for example:

   instead of:

   ```py
   E1 = Entry (top, bd = 5,).grid( row = 1 , column = 1)
   ```

   use:

   ```py
   E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5,)
   E1.grid( row = 1 , column = 1)
   ```
2. Use `from tkinter import messagebox` instead of `import tkinter.messagebox`.

#### Minimal working code

Below should be the working code with minimal changes

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox


def process():
    try :
        number1 = Entry.get(E1)
        number2 = Entry.get(E2)
        operator = Entry.get(E3)
        number1 = int(number1)
        number2 = int(number2)
        if operator == "+" :
            answer = number1 + number2
        Entry.insert(E4,0,answer)
        print(answer)
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please enter the value in integer")

top = tkinter.Tk()


L1 = Label(top, text ='My calculator',)
L1.grid(row = 0 , column = 1)

L2 = Label(top, text = "Number 1",)
L2.grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

L3 = Label(top, text = 'Number 2',)
L3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

L4 = Label(top, text = 'Operator',)
L4.grid(row=3, column = 0)

L5 = Label(top, text = 'Answer:',)
L5.grid( row = 4, column = 0)

E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5,)
E1.grid( row = 1 , column = 1)

E2 = Entry( top , bd = 5,)
E2.grid( row = 2, column = 1)

E3 = Entry( top, bd = 5,)
E3.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

E4 = Entry( top, bd = 5,)
E4.grid(row=4, column= 1 )

B = Button(top, text = "Submit here: ", command = process)
B.grid(row = 5 , column = 1,)


top.mainloop()
```